# RPN PostFix Calculator output not as expected for simple arithmetic

Tags: java, calculator, rpn

I have written a class to do post fix calculations on the basic arithmetic operators - the code is below.

```
public class PostFixCalculatorRPN
{
    public static void main()
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("PostFix expression: ");
        Stack s = new Stack();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
            {
                // pop 2 numbers off and operate
                switch (ch)
                {
                case '+':// push the sum of the 2 numbers back on stack
                case '-': // push the difference of the 2 numbers back on stack
                case '*': // push the product of the 2 numbers back on stack    
                case '/':// push the quotient of the 2 numbers back on stack
                }
            } else
                s.push(ch + "");
        }
        int answer = Integer.parseInt((String) s.pop());

        System.out.println(printInput(input) + ": Evaluates to -> " + answer);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String printInput(String s)
    {
        String str = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            str += s.charAt(i);

        return str;
    }
}
```

I believe that the `Stack` class I have with this works correctly, but I can post that as well if necessary.

The output of my calculator is not as expected, for example an input of `53+` evaluates to `3` and `92*` evaluates to `2`, whereas I was expecting `8` and `18` respectively.

Comment: "output incorrect" Can you give at least 1 example of an input/output pairing of your current application?

Comment: Yes, for example "53+" evaluates to 3. "92*" evaluates to 2.

Comment: For RPN, I'm not sure what "53+" should evaluate to. You have one number (53) and an operator (+) that requires two numbers. I mean "5 3 +" should evaluate to 8. Isn't that space essential?

Comment: When I add a space like you said I get a number format exception error

Comment: Ah so reading a little between the lines of what I can see I'm guessing you are just reading one character at a time and assuming everything is a 1-digit number. So no spaces. That sound right?

Comment: What code is in your case statements?? If nothing (like in your post), then of course it's just going to return the last number placed on the stack.

Comment: Yes I guess my question is how do I fill in those case statements?

Comment: Well you pushed all the numbers you've hit onto the stack for a reason right? So pop two numbers off the stack and add them (first case statement). Then push the result onto the stack.

Comment: Yes I have that in the comments but I cannot get the code right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have is really close but without code in your case statements it will simply return the last non-operator in your input string (last item pushed onto stack). Do you understand completely the code you have and what a stack is? You are stepping left to right through the input and pushing numbers onto the stack until you hit an operator (+-*/) and then applying the operator to those numbers you conveniently pushed on the stack. These numbers pop off in reverse order that you pushed them on. You should just need to pop two numbers off the stack and then perform the desired operation and push the result. Something like (reusing pieces already in your code):

```
s.push(Integer.parseInt((String)s.pop()) + Integer.parseInt((String)s.pop()) + "");
```

One of the operators will be slightly trickier due to ordering of the pops. Just think about it.

Comment: Ok so wouldn't I need two variables to operate on in the case statements? I understand how stacks work but I am new to Java syntax.

Comment: Your edit to add that picture has been [rejected by a number of reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7389547) - You might consider adding a link to it in comments - e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/nPKqM.jpg . I came to have a look at the question for context on reviewing the edit and fixed up your post formatting a bit too - you'll tend to get more people looking through the post if it looks nice, although I think @MarkBalhoff is helping you out here.

Comment: Correct. You can store the numbers in variables but it is not necessary for the addition case statement,

Comment: @MikeG The code in your image is close but the subtract and divide are wrong. Also, for consistency with your string stack you might need `+ ""` like you had done later in your code. Are you still getting any errors?

Comment: Yes I am getting incompatible types error for "int operand1 = s.pop();"

Comment: @MikeG oh I didn't pay close attention to that line. s.pop() returns a string. You need to parse that to an int to store it in the int variable operand1. So like... `int operand1 = Integer.parseInt((String)s.pop());`

Comment: Ok, that part worked now I am getting "Method push in class Stack cannot be applied to given types..." for the "s.push" part in the first case statement.

Comment: Did you add the empty string on the end like you did on your later push? `s.push(operand1 + operand2 + "")` My guess is your push method wants a string and you are passing an int.

Comment: Ok great it complies, but the output of "53+" is "0".

Comment: Do you have your `break;` statements in your switch case? You don't on the image you posted. We don't want to fall through the cases.

Comment: Ok great all operators work except for division(/). They all output 0.

Comment: @MikeG Can you take another screenshot and provide the link **here in the comments**?

Comment: [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/ofmy2v.png                                                                                   [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/dbjvaq.png

Comment: @MikeG With input `53+`, what are the values of operand1 and operand2 respectively when you reach the case statement?

Comment: Oh yes I see what you are getting at so `48/` is `2` but `84/` is `0`. Should I flip operand1 and operand2 for all statements or just division?

Comment: @MikeG Well for addition and multiplication order does not matter. But both subtraction and division need to flip the operands because `84/` leads to push 8 push 4 pop 4 pop 8. So we need operand2 to come first.

Comment: Ok, I switched them and everything works great. I really appreciate you helping and your time!